# Why email freezes in the smtplib.SMTP_SSL function?

Tags: python

The smtplib.SMTP_SSL line freezes for 12 seconds, but on another pc(`Version: Python - 3.11.0`) the whole function works for less than 1 second.

`Version: Python - 3.11.0`

```
import email.mime.application, smtplib, imaplib, email, base64
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
def send_email_from_SO(from_send: list, to_send: list, subject: str, text: str):
    """
    :param from_send: [login, password, SMTP]
    :param to_send: [login]
    :param subject: "Subject"
    :param text: "Text"
    :return: ---
    """
    start_time = time.time()
    print(f"p1: {(time.time() - start_time)}")
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = MIMEMultipart() # email.mime.Multipart.
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_send[0]
    msg['To'] = to_send[0]
    body = MIMEText(text)
    msg.attach(body)
    print(f"p2: {(time.time() - start_time)}")
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(from_send[3], 465)
    print(f"p3: {(time.time() - start_time)}")
    s.login(from_send[0], from_send[1])
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    print(f"p4: {(time.time() - start_time)}")
```

```
p1: 0.0
p2: 0.0010004043579101562
p3: 12.056276321411133
p4: 12.748610734939575
```

I tried changing the string
`s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(from_send[3], 465)`
to
`s = smtplib.SMTP(from_send[3])`
`s.starttls()`
For a running time of also 12 seconds. What should I do to make the string work faster.

Comment: My guess: probably network I/O and negotiating the encryption algorithm. Try to turn on debugging to see the actual SMTP commands being sent and the replies received. Maybe a firewall.